Is the complement of a square imbedded to a cylinder connected?
Let $C$ be a compact 2-dimensional cylinder $[0,1]\times S^1$. Let $A$, $A'$ be the two connected components of its boundary.
Let $Q$ be a square. Let $a$, $a'$ be a pair of opposite edges of $Q$.
Consider a smooth imbedding $f\colon Q\to C$ such that
$$f(a)\subset A,\, \, f(a')\subset A'.$$
Assume moreover that $f(\partial Q\setminus (a\cup a'))$ in contained in the interior of $C$.
Question. Is it true that $C\setminus f(Q)$ is connected?
A reference will be helpful.

What does $f(\partial C)$ mean? Isn't $f$ defined on $Q$?

I would assume it was supposed to mean $f(Q\backslash (a\cup a'))$...

@YaakovBaruch: Sorry, corrected.

Take a look at the theory of surfaces, and embedded curves in those surfaces.  There is a basic theory of how cutting along embedded curves affects the surface: its genus and number of boundary components.    You can derive the theory from the classification of surfaces, or simply from Poincare Duality.

@RyanBudney; Do you have a reference to this theory? A more focused information would be helpful.

By Moore’s quotient theorem, if a continuous onto map $f$ from the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ to a Hausdorff space $X$ has acyclic fibers, then $f$ can be approximated by a homeomorphism; in particular, $X$ is
homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$. It seems that your statement follows from this theorem, pass to the quotient with one-point set instead of each boundary component.

C may be seen as a plane annulus. Joining the other 2 edges of the imbedded square and the arcs A\f(a) and A'\f(a') one gets a simple closed curve, and I'd say C\f(Q) is connected by the Jordan curve thm.
